# no puedo listar con ajax php y jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, json

Al intentar listar los productos me da un error, lo curioso es que localmente me funciona muy bien pero al hacer el deploy me muestra el error 
"DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"
voy a adjustar imagenes del problema con el código, si alguien me puede orientar lo agradezco.

este es el código de listar product.php:

```
<div class="table-responsive col-lg-12">
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" data-source="data-source" id="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id Product</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Supplier</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Photo</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

este otro sería ajax_producto.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    listar();
});

function listar() {

  var table = $("#datatable").DataTable({
       "order": [[0, "desc" ]],
       "bFilter": true,
       "bDestroy": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "ajax": {
          "type": "POST",
          "url": "../admin/list_.php"
        },
        "columns": [
          { "data": "productid"},
          { "data": "product_name"},
          { "data": "company_name"},
          { "data": "category_name"},
          { "data": "categoryid", "class":"hidden"},
          { "data": "company_address", "class":"hidden"},
          { "data": "contact", "class":"hidden"},
          { "data": "description", "class":"hidden"},
          { "data": "supplierid", "class":"hidden"},
          { "data": "tech", "class":"hidden"},
          { "data": "userid", "class":"hidden"},
          { "data": "video", "class":"hidden"},
          { "data": "product_price" },
          { "data": "product_qty"},
          { "data": "photo", render: getImg},
          { "data": "photo", "class":"hidden"},
          { "data": null,"defaultContent": "<div class='btns'><button class='btn btn-success btnEditar'><span class='fa fa-pencil'></span> Edit</button> | <button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminar'><span class='fa fa-trash'></span> Delete</button></div>"}
        ]
    });
}
```

este sería list_.php:

```
<?php
include('session.php');

$pq = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from product left join category on category.categoryid=product.categoryid left join supplier on supplier.userid=product.supplierid");
$data["data"] = mysqli_fetch_all($pq,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```

adjunto imagenes.

lado del server (godaddy)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

local
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seguro es alguna configuración del servidor, inspeccione la petición en la pestaña network de su navegador, seguro está devolviendo el error como respuesta _(tab response)_  el error puede ser que no cuente con el driver mysqlnd.

Comment: en response payload lo que me tira es 1, y en preview no me sale nada

Comment: Al ingresar a la [URL de la petición](http://www.fchmaintenanceservices.com/POS/admin/list_.php) , arroja un error 500 y el motivo puede ser diferentes factores. tiempo de espera _(por mysqli_fetch_all)_ , configuraciones, etc.

Comment: algún consejo de que podría revisar?

Comment: Abre la consola del navegador (yo uso Chrome), en la pestaña Network. En list_.php pon un var_dump de $data, para ver que se está generando la matriz correctamente. Si es así, por mi experiencia puedes tener dos problemas: 1) que alguno de los datos de la matriz no esté en UTF-8. Por si acaso, a cada dato añádele mb_convert_encoding. Recuerda que json_encode solo funciona cuando todos los datos están en UTF8.
Otro tema que también me dió problemas en una ocasión era que tenía el datatables bajo https y el script php bajo http. No se si será tu caso, pero es otro tema que puedes comprobar.

Comment: También puedes revisar el error.log del servidor para más detalles. Puede que hayas errado con el usuario y contraseña de mysql en el servidor y por eso en local te funciona.

Comment: ¿Has probado a seguir las indicaciones del apartado Diagnosis que te sugiere el enlace que nos pones en tu pregunta? ahí debe de estar diciendo el problema y para más detalles, tal como te digo en mi otro comentario, deberías revisar el fichero error.log del servidor, seguro que el error concreto está ahí.